# I am trying to save space, am I allowed to remove the footer and space between footnotes according to Turabian formatting? (see image)

Tags: essay, chicago-manual-of-style

[image]

I have a limit of 15 pages for this paper so I am trying to save as much space as possible, so I was wondering what I could do to remove blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit recommendation for the spacing between the body of the text and the footnotes in *A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations*.

According to Appendix A.1.3, there should be one blank line between items *within* the footnotes as well as between items within other sections such as the table of contents:

> The following items should be single-spaced internally but with a blank line between items:
>
> - certain elements in the front matter (see A.2.1), including the table of contents and any list of figures, tables, or abbreviations
> - footnotes or endnotes
> - bibliographies or reference lists

This seems to indicate that **one blank line is the minimium spacing between elements of your text**.

A sample page with footnotes in the *Manual* shows a spacing between body text and footnotes that is similar to yours (p. 406):

[image: Figure showing a sample page with footnotes]

I therefore assume that it is fine, but I wouldn't go under one blank line.

---

If you need to save more space, you might use endnotes if your guidelines allow this. The *Manual* recommends endnotes only if the number of footnotes would begin to overwhelm the body text. There should be *two* blank lines before the beginning of the endnotes.

---

*Note.*

Your footnotes seem to be too close together!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, I put the margins back to normal and put a blank line between the footnotes.